# VSCode extension get workspace state

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've VSCode extension and I need to know if user is using multiroot projects view (multiple projects are opened )
or just one project, how should I differentiate  ?

I try with the following:

```
if (!workspace.workspaceFolders || workspace.workspaceFolders.length < 2) {
    console.dir(`workspace folders ${JSON.stringify(workspace.workspaceFolders)}  && workspace length ${workspace.workspaceFolders?.length}`)
}
```

But it doesn't works give me that data, is there other way to achive this ?

this is what I need

> 1. if user open a project directly
> 2. if user open more then on project using multi root mode
> 3. if user open one project in multi root mode (maybe it's like the first)

Comment: what are the results you see in the different cases

Comment: @rioV8 - same results, am I using it wrong?

Comment: just use your `console.dir` without the if statement and try it out on different use cases and see what the results are.

Comment: @rioV8 - I got the same results, how should I differentiate? is there diffrent api?

Comment: when I log `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.length` it's value is `1` for `Open Folder` or `>1` for `Multi Root Workspace`